# Issue with running Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

          <title>ggl</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 </head>
 <script src="js\angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 function Customer($scope){
   $scope.CustomerName="bob";
   $scope.CustomerCode="200";
 }
 var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
 myApp.controller("Customer", Customer);



 </script>
 <body>

   <div id="CustScreen" ng-controller="Customer">
     Customer Name :-<input ng-model="CustomerName"type="text" id="CustomerName">
     Customer Code :-<input ng-model="CustomerCode"type="text" id="CustomerCode">
     <div id="divCustomerName">{{CustomerName}}</div>
     <div id="divCustomerName">{{CustomerCode}}</div><br/>
   </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

The outcome when I run the program is that it prints {{CustomerName}} in the div and not the expected input name. I am unsure if it is a problem with the code itself or the linking I have made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your script is between the `<head>` and `<body>` tag, but that's probably not the issue here. The issue is most likely because you forgot to add

```
ng-app="myApp"
```

on one of your root elements e.g. `<html ng-app="myApp">`.

Without that attribute, angular doesn't know where to start bootstrapping the application.

Answer (score 0):

You havent added ng-app directive in the HTML. Replace `<html>` as `<html ng-app="myApp">`